# How do display array in array?

Tags: angular

I have an array in a list and when selecting a value, another list of the array should be displayed.

How do I display an array under an array?

**html:**

```html
<li *ngFor="let category of (categories$ | async)">
    <a  (click)="loadSubCategories(category)">{{category.categoryName}}</a>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of (subCategories$ | async)">
        <a>{{data.categoryName}}</a>
    </ng-container>
</li>
```

**ts:**

```js
categories$!: Observable<CategoryI[]>
    
subCategories$!: Observable<CategoryI[]>;
      
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.categories$ = this.categoryService.fetch();
}
    
loadSubCategories(data: CategoryI) {
    this.subCategories$ = this.categoryService.findDescendants(data.id);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by duplicating arrays?

Comment: @VítorFrança If you do the same as shown in my example. Arrays will be repeated

Comment: Kindly share your data result as well.

Comment: Pretty inefficient way! Why not fetch both parent and child elements in one go and display the children on click event? And do this: `categories$: Observable<CategoryI[]> = EMPTY`. `EMPTY` is imported from `'rxjs'`.

Comment: @msrumon In order not to load all the elements at once and thereby speed up the get request.

Comment: Fair enough. Since it's a deferred event, what I think you should opt for is to return direct data, instead of observable. I don't think, based on the template you've provided, you need an observable there. Just return `Promise<CategoryI>` from the `findDescendents()` method. You can still "await" for the promise to be resolved using the same `async` pipe in the template.

Comment: Do you want somthing like that?

<ng-container *ngIf="{ subCategories: subCategories$ | async }; let subCategoriesObj;">
<div *ngFor="let data of subCategoriesObj.subCategories">
<a>{{data.categoryName}}</a>